# How should Domain Services call Infrastructure services?

Tags: domain-driven-design

1) When *Domain layer* is using an *Infrastructure Service* **IS**, then its interface is defined within a *Domain layer*, while its implementation is defined within an *Infrastructure layer*.

We shouldn't inject **IS** ( such as a Repository or E-mail service) directly into *Domain entities*:

```
class Foo
{
       IRepository repo;
           ...
       public int DoSomething()
       {
            var info = repo.Get...;
              ...
       }
}
```

Instead, if a some method of a *Domain Entity* needs a particular **IS**, then *Application layer* could pass that **IS** as an argument to that method:

```
 class Foo
{
           ...
       public int DoSomething(IRepository repo)
       {
            var info = repo.Get...;
              ...
       }
}
```

a) I assume **IS** also shouldn't be injected directly into *Domain Services*:

```
class TransferService
{
         IRepository repo;
             ...
         public bool Transfer()
         {
            var info = repo.Get...;
              ...
         } 
}
```

, but instead **IS** should be passed as an argument to those methods of *Domain Service* which intend to use it:

```
class TransferService
{
         public bool Transfer(IRepository repo)
         {
            var info = repo.Get...;
              ...
         } 
}
```

b) I assume if a method of *Domain Entity* needs to use a *Domain Service*, it doesn't need to receive it via an argument ( though passing *Domain Service* as an argument has a benefit of explicitly conveying method's dependencies ), but instead can call it directly, reason being that both *Domain Entity* and *Domain Service* are both domain concepts:

```
class Foo
{
       ...

       public int DoSomething()
       {
            var info = TransferService.Transfer(...);
              ...
       }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

1)

> An IS can be injected into a domain service if it needs it for
>   functionality - ie not passed to method. This is different than
>   entities and it is because a domain service is stateless and so it can
>   be configured with required dependencies once and used where needed,
>   such as by other entities.

a) So major reason why **IS** shouldn't be injected into *Domain Entities* is due to their statefulf nature?

b) But I thought primary reason for not to injecting **IS** into *Domain Entities* is because it would violate *Persistence Ignorance* rule?

c) What problems does statefull nature of an entity cause if we inject it with **IS**?

d) Doesn't injecting **IS** into *Domain Service* violate PI? If not, why not?

2)

> A domain service should be passed to entity as argument much like you
>   would pass a repository interface as argument. The same principles
>   apply.

But unlike *Repository* a *Domain Service* is a domain concept, so what do you mean by "same principles apply"? Namely, injecting *Domain Service* into *Domain Entity* wouldn't violate **PI** while injecting a *Repository* would!

**SECOND UPDATE:**

1)

a)

> That is one reason. Another is that is creates needless coupling. If a
>   repository is needed for only a single behavior on the entity, why
>   inject it into entity all the time? Also, now you have to consider how
>   you will resolve those dependencies? Make entities part of dependency
>   injection graph? This quickly overloads the responsibilities of the
>   entity.

So if I understood you correctly - Injecting **IS** into *Domain Service* **DS** doesn't violate SRP,  because **DS** is using it to execute its designated tasks ( ie its designated responsibility), while injecting **IS** into *Domain Entity* is a violation of SRP because primary responsibility of *Domain Entity* is focusing on its life cycle and identity, and **IS** most of the times isn't an integral part in managing these two tasks ( ie focusing on life cycle and identity )?

b)

> You can still pass an IS to a domain entity method and the problem
>   here wouldn't be violation of PI since you're passing an interface,
>   not an implementation. The problem would be violation of SRP if the
>   domain method only used one method on the IS interface.

I - But in several of your previous posts you noted that it's ok to pass **IS** as an argument to a method of *Domain Entity*, but here you're saying that it would violate SRP if this domain method used only one method on **IS** instance?

II - If **IS** implemented a role-based interface containing a single method, and instead we pass this role-based interface as an argument to domain method, would you still consider this as a violation of SRP? If not, why not?

d)

> PI is maintained with the use of interfaces.

I've read several times that even if domain method is referencing a repository via an interface, it's still considered a violation of PI. Why don't you agree with that?

2)

> It is better however to be very explicit. So instead of passing a
>   repository and implicitly understanding that it happens to provide a
>   service to the entity, declare the provided functionality as its own
>   interface and have the entity depend on that.

a) So single reason for not injecting *Domain Service* into *Domain Entity* is due to violation of SRP?

b)

> declare the provided functionality as its own interface

I assume you're suggesting to use role-based interfaces? But wouldn't even injecting a role-based interface  ( implemented by say *Domain Service* ) into *Domain Entity* cause violation of SRP, since as you noted in **1a**, the injected functionality would most probably be needed only for a single behavior of *Domain Entity*?!

It appears you and Aaron Hawkins are on the opposite sides with regards to passing **IS** to methods of *Domain Entities*?!

**THIRD UPDATE:**

1)

a)

> > So if I understood you correctly - Injecting IS into Domain Service DS
> >     doesn't violate SRP, because DS is using it to execute its designated
> >     tasks ( ie its designated responsibility), while injecting IS into
> >     Domain Entity is a violation of SRP because primary responsibility of
> >     Domain Entity is focusing on its life cycle and identity, and ISmost
> >     of the times isn't an integral part in managing these two tasks ( ie
> >     focusing on life cycle and identity )?
>
> Yes that is correct and one of the primary reasons.

I - From the distance it seems perfectly reasonable how by injecting **IS** into *Domain Entity* **DE**, this **DE** would violate SRP, because **IS** won't contribute to managing the two task designated to **DE**.

But it's a bit harder when trying to imagine this scenario in more detail. Namely, if methods of **DE** are focused on managing the two designated task ( ie its life cycle and identity ), then if one of these methods needs **IS**, wouldn't it be reasonable to assume it needs **IS** to accomplish the two designated task and not some other task unrelated to **DE's** life cycle and identity? If yes, then how could we claim **DE** violates SRP?

II - I also have hard time imagining what exactly is meant by managing **DE's** life cycle and identity. For starters, once **DE** is assigned an identity, this identity doesn't change. So what about its identity would we need to manage?

III - And what is meant by managing **DE's** life cycle? Perhaps defining the invariants on **DE** which keep its data consistent or ...?

IV -  So all other tasks ( ie those that aren't related to DE's life cycle and identity )  that real world entity performs should  be factored out from **DE** and put into related objects?

d)

> > If IS implemented a role-based interface containing a single method,
> >     and instead we pass this role-based interface as an argument to domain
> >     method, would you still consider this as a violation of SRP? If not,
> >     why not?
>
> It isn't terrible to do it, but it has potential to violate SRP or as
>   more clearly specified by guillaume31 - ISP.

I'm not sure how we can claim injecting **IS** into **DE** could violate **ISP**, since to my knowledge **ISP** can only be violated by an object that implements this interface and not an object into which an implementation of this interface is injected?

**FOURTH UPDATE:**

I'm beginning to realize SRP is way more confusing than I initially thought

a)

> Behavior associated with the entity, which usually entails state
>   changes, should also be placed into the entity. If such behavior
>   requires use of a service, pass that service in, but generally try to
>   place as much behavior into the entity as possible.

IV – 1 The following behavioral methods don't include state changes, but I gather they too should belong to a `Dog` entity:

```
class Dog
{
            ...
       void DoBark();
       void DoFetch();
       void DoGuard();

       Breed    GetBreed();
       Pedigree GetPedigree();
       Snack    FavSnack();
}
```

IV – b) Are `GetBreed`, `GetPedigree` and `FavSnack` behavioral methods? If yes, then properties `Breed`, `Pedigree` and `Snack` should also be considered as behaviors, since they essentially provide the same functionality ( assuming that `GetBreed`, `GetPedigree` and `FavSnack` don't do some heavy computation, but simply return the objects ):

```
class Dog
{
            ...
       void DoBark();
       void DoFetch();
       void DoGuard();

       Breed    Breed { get{...} }
       Pedigree Pedigree { get{...} }
       Snack    Snack { get{...} }
}
```

IV – c) if above properties also had *setters*, would we say they contain *state-changing behavior*?

IV – d)

> Behavior associated with the entity, which usually entails state
>   changes, should also be placed into the entity.

But if main responsibility of *Domain Entity* is managing its life cycle, then wouldn't including behavior not related to managing the life cycle be a violation of SRP ( in above example, methods such as `Dog.DoBark` most probably don't have much to do with `Dog`'s life cycle)?!

d)

I.

> Passing IS to a DE behavioral method is better, however can violate
>   SRP/ISP if IS interface has lots of things unrelated to the behavior
>   at hand. This is the basic premise of ISP - dependencies should be
>   made on specific interfaces as opposed to bloated interfaces that
>   happen to contain the required functionality.

so if **IS** passed as an argument to one of DE's *behavioral methods* does have some operations unrelated to behavior at hand, but DE's method **M** doesn't use any of **IS**'s methods unrelated to behavior **M** should be handling, we still consider DE to be violating SRP/ISP?

II. – I understand what you're saying, but my confusion steams from the fact that according to the following definitions of ISP, the term should only be used to designate that an object **ServObj** implementing  a particular interface is violating ISP, while object into which **ServObj** is injected is violating SRP ( due to receiving **ServObj** ):

> The Interface Segregation Principle is similar to the Single
>   Responsibility Principle in that both deal with the cohesion of
>   responsibilities. In fact, the ISP can be understood as the
>   application of the SRP to an object’s public interface.
>
> To a certain extent, ISP can be considered a sub-set, or more specific
>   form of the Single Responsibility Principle. The perspective shift of
>   ISP, though, examines the public API for a given class or module.

thank you

Comment: It seems you're mixing up responsibility with collaboration. An object can perfectly need multiple collaborators (either injected into it via its constructor or passed as arguments of methods) in order to achieve its sole responsibility. This doesn't violate SRP. Injecting a collaborator != adding a responsibility.

Comment: @guillaume31: A - So you don't agree with eulerfx that injecting a collaborator breaks SRP of an entity? B - with regards to your comment about ISP - can't ISP be violated only by object that implements the interface and not an object into which this interface implementation is injected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1a) An IS can be injected into a domain service if it needs it for functionality - ie not passed to method. This is different than entities and it is because a domain service is stateless and so it can be configured with required dependencies once and used where needed, such as by other entities.

1b) A domain service should be passed to entity as argument much like you would pass a repository interface as argument. The same principles apply. Also, passing entire repository interface can create needless coupling and so it is better to declare and pass a role specific interface.

**UPDATE**

1a) That is one reason. Another is that is creates needless coupling. If a repository is needed for only a single behavior on the entity, why inject it into entity all the time? Also, now you have to consider how you will resolve those dependencies? Make entities part of dependency injection graph? This quickly overloads the responsibilities of the entity.

1b) Violation of PI is an instance of the more general concept of violating the single responsibility principle. You can still pass an IS to a domain entity method and the problem here wouldn't be violation of PI since you're passing an interface, not an implementation. The problem would be violation of SRP if the domain method only used one method on the IS interface.

1c) See 1a)

1d) No because PI is maintained with the use of interfaces.

2) Yes, which is why I would suggest avoiding passing repository interfaces directly. The principles are similar because you can think of both a repository interface and a domain service as abstract services that provide some behavior interesting for a domain entity. It is better however to be very explicit. So instead of passing a repository and implicitly understanding that it happens to provide a service to the entity, declare the provided functionality as its own interface and have the entity depend on that.

**UPDATE 2**

1a) Yes that is correct and one of the primary reasons.

1b) It isn't terrible to do it, but it has potential to violate SRP or as more clearly specified by **guillaume31** - [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). So it is better than say injecting into entity instance, but could be improved by declaring a specific interface.

And no, if you create a role-based interface then this is as good as it gets in this scenario.

1d) If an entity uses a repository interface to persist itself then this is a violation of PI. However, if it uses a repository interface to perform some query in order to run its business logic, then we're not really talking about persistence. And to really decouple the repository, employ a role specific interface instead.

2a) Yes, for the same reason that it isn't appropriate to inject repository into entity.

2b) Yes, but I'm only suggesting that in the scenario where you're passing a domain service to a behavioral method on the entity, not injecting it into the entity instance itself.

**UPDATE 3**

1a) This can be a point of contention I agree. However, from a practical point of view, it is better to design DEs such that their dependencies on external services are either eliminated or made very explicit and isolated. If your DE has an instance dependency on an IS, that means that whenever an instance of the DE is created, such as during reconstitution or when creating a new entity, the IS must be provided at that time. This complicates the dependency graph. Moreover, if a DE is responsible for maintaining the integrity of its own state, why would there be a dependency on an external service? There may be a need for a service to invoke some behavior, but to maintaining integrity can usually be accomplished without external services. In fact, dependencies on external services in this way is usually a smell of conflated responsibilities.

II, III) This includes such things as protecting invariants. For example, an entity could ensure that its values don't get into an inconsistent state by raising an exception. This is a fundamental premise of OOP - encapsulate state and expose behavior.

IV) Behavior associated with the entity, which usually entails state changes, should also be placed into the entity. If such behavior requires use of a service, pass that service in, but generally try to place as much behavior into the entity as possible. This won't always be perfect, but you can strive for the ideal.

d) To be sure, when I say injecting IS I mean having a required instance reference to an IS from a DE. This is discouraged for reasons above. Passing IS to a DE behavioral method is better, however can violate SRP/ISP if IS interface has lots of things unrelated to the behavior at hand. This is the basic premise of ISP - dependencies should be made on specific interfaces as opposed to bloated interfaces that happen to contain the required functionality.

Comment: "The problem would be violation of SRP if the domain method only used one method on the IS interface." - you mean violation of **ISP**, right ?

Comment: @guillaume31 yes, SRP, ISP, they are all essentially the same

Comment: Can you see my update? Regardless, your post deserved to be marked two updates ago

Answer (score 3):

The domain entities should know nothing about persistence (repositories) or processes (domain services).  Instead, your application will orchestrate these together.

Here is the repository orchestration for example:

```
ISomeAggregateRepository repository = //TODO: Construct repository and load it with the de-hydrated aggregates you intend to work with under your scope.
foreach (SomeAggregate someAggregate in repository) //The repository functions like an in memory collection.
{
    someAggregate.DoSomethingCool(); //The domain aggregate would expose an event to let the repository know that this method has been called and that the instance should be saved afterwards. (mimicking saving to a reference)
}
```

Here is the domain service orchestration for example:

```
ISomeDomainService service = new ConcreteInfrastructuralSpecificDomainService();
service.DoSomethingCool(SomeAggregate target); //Send the aggregate to the domain service, not the other way around.
```

I was on the same track as you for the longest time and was very confused, but once I figured out how to organize the code in the way my examples depict, things became much more clear.

Just remember that the application should be what chooses the implementation (usually infrastructure specific) of your repositories, domain services, and potentially your unit of work.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

> A - You mean only Application layer should create and use Domain Services, while Domain Entities shouldn't even know they exist? But why?

Here are a few that I came up with off the top of my head.  I wouldn't consider this a complete list, but should be enough to warrant my statement.

- Encapsulation (The inner workings of the domain aggregates are not exposed to implementations of the would-be passed repositories and/or domain services)
- Repositories/Domain Services are inherently infrastructure and as such, should not be combined into your business domain which keeps your business logic clean and expressive. (The interfaces are in the domain to provide implementers a contractual way of implementing repositories/domain services preventing the need for an application to reference more projects than needed.)
- Making your domain ignorant of repositories/domain services further enforces the decoupling and possible dependency that would be going in the wrong direction (infrastructure project should reference domain project, not vice versa which could happen if someone implements your domain without dependency injection by passing in a *referenced* concrete implementation).
- Change Management/Maintainability (see [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/))

> B - I assume all of the code you posted resides within Application layer?

You are correct good sir!

Comment: A - "Just remember that the application should be what chooses the implementation (usually infrastructure specific) of your repositories, domain services ..." You mean only Application layer should create and use Domain Services, while Domain Entities shouldn't even know they exist? But why? B - I assume all of the code you posted resides within Application layer?

Comment: "Encapsulation (The inner workings of the domain aggregates are not exposed to implementations of the would-be passed repositories and/or domain services)" How would passing Repositories/Domain Services to a Domain Entity expose its inner workings ( perhaps you're suggesting that methods on domain entities should be exposed to Application layer )?

Comment: Maybe exposed was the wrong word.  If you're passing the repositories/domain services into the entity for the entity to call, you may end up writing code inside your repository/domain service expecting the entity to be in a particular state when that method is called which means that it will be expecting the call at a certain stage within the domain method.  This breaks encapsulation because the repository/domain service should not care (aside from validation) what state the domain entity is in.  The entity should be able to be persisted or processed regardless of its state.